# How to block row to be selected in Oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle, select, oracle9i, policy

We have table in database, using Oracle 9i(9.2), we must made policy for SELECT query, some group of users can access for exact row and some cannot, standardly it solved by VIEWs:

- making some VIEW table
- changing table name of origin

But there is a problem, we can't change table name, it bureaucracy problems.

Finally, is it some mechanism or triggers(there are no triggers for SELECT but just example) to control row access?

Sorry, if question is dummy,I don't have much experience with DBs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create a [Virtual Private Database policy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm) for the table in question.

From a presentation I did a couple years ago

Set up the environment

```
-- The SEMOP user has been granted the following privileges
--   CREATE SESSION
--   CREATE PROCEDURE
--   CREATE ANY CONTEXT
--   UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
--   CREATE TABLE
--   CREATE SEQUENCE
--   EXECUTE ON DBMS_RLS
--   EXECUTE ON DBMS_FGA
--   SELECT ON DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL

conn oow2009/oow2009;

create table patient (
  patient_id         number primary key,
  patient_first_name varchar2(30),
  patient_last_name  varchar2(30),
  vip_flag           char(1)
);

create table service (
  service_id         number primary key,
  service_name       varchar2(30)
);

create table doctor (
  doctor_id          number primary key,
  doctor_first_name  varchar2(30),
  doctor_last_name   varchar2(30),
  service_id         number references service( service_id )
);

create table admission (
  admission_id       number primary key,
  patient_id         number references patient( patient_id ),
  service_id         number references service( service_id ),
  primary_doctor_id  number references doctor( doctor_id ),
  admission_date     date,
  discharge_date     date
);

begin
  insert into patient( patient_id, patient_first_name, patient_last_name, vip_flag )
    values( 1, 'Barack', 'Obama', 'Y' );
  insert into patient( patient_id, patient_first_name, patient_last_name, vip_flag )
    values( 2, 'Larry', 'Ellison', 'Y' );
  insert into patient( patient_id, patient_first_name, patient_last_name, vip_flag )
    values( 3, 'Justin', 'Cave', 'N' );
  insert into patient( patient_id, patient_first_name, patient_last_name, vip_flag )
    values( 4, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'N' );

  insert into service( service_id, service_name )
    values( 11, 'Obstetrics' );
  insert into service( service_id, service_name )
    values( 12, 'Cardiac' );
  insert into service( service_id, service_name )
    values( 13, 'Opthamology' );
  insert into service( service_id, service_name )
    values( 14, 'Emergency' );

  insert into doctor( doctor_id, doctor_first_name, doctor_last_name, service_id )
    values( 21, 'William', 'Mayo', 14 );  
  insert into doctor( doctor_id, doctor_first_name, doctor_last_name, service_id )
    values( 22, 'George', 'Minot', 13 );  
  insert into doctor( doctor_id, doctor_first_name, doctor_last_name, service_id )
    values( 23, 'Richard', 'Morton', 12 );  
  insert into doctor( doctor_id, doctor_first_name, doctor_last_name, service_id )
    values( 24, 'Carl', 'Jung', 11 );  
  insert into doctor( doctor_id, doctor_first_name, doctor_last_name, service_id )
    values( 25, 'Joseph', 'Lister', 12 );  

  -- Obama has been admitted 3 times, twice for heart tests and once for an eye test  
  insert into admission( admission_id, patient_id, service_id, primary_doctor_id, admission_date, discharge_date )
    values( 31, 1, 12, 23, date '2009-04-01', date '2009-04-01' );  
  insert into admission( admission_id, patient_id, service_id, primary_doctor_id, admission_date, discharge_date )
    values( 32, 1, 12, 25, date '2009-05-03', date '2009-05-03' );  
  insert into admission( admission_id, patient_id, service_id, primary_doctor_id, admission_date, discharge_date )
    values( 33, 1, 13, 22, date '2009-05-03', date '2009-05-03' );  

  -- Ellison was admitted to the emergency department following a yachting accident  
  insert into admission( admission_id, patient_id, service_id, primary_doctor_id, admission_date, discharge_date )
    values( 34, 2, 14, 21, date '2009-07-01', date '2009-07-03' );  

  -- Justin was admitted earlier today for an eye exam and hasn't been discharged
  insert into admission( admission_id, patient_id, service_id, primary_doctor_id, admission_date, discharge_date )
    values( 35, 3, 13, 22, date '2009-09-24', null );  

  -- Jane was admitted to obstatrics
  insert into admission( admission_id, patient_id, service_id, primary_doctor_id, admission_date, discharge_date )
    values( 36, 4, 11, 24, date '2009-08-01', date '2009-08-10' );  
end;
/
```

Create a secure context

```
create or replace context oow2009_ctx
 using pkg_secure_context;    

create or replace package pkg_secure_context 
as 
  procedure login( p_doctor_first_name IN doctor.doctor_first_name%TYPE,
                   p_doctor_last_name  IN doctor.doctor_last_name%TYPE );

  procedure logout;                   
end;
/

create or replace package body pkg_secure_context
as
  procedure login( p_doctor_first_name IN doctor.doctor_first_name%TYPE,
                   p_doctor_last_name  IN doctor.doctor_last_name%TYPE )
  as
    l_doctor_id doctor.doctor_id%TYPE;
  begin
    SELECT doctor_id
      INTO l_doctor_id
      FROM doctor
     WHERE doctor_first_name = p_doctor_first_name
       AND doctor_last_name  = p_doctor_last_name;

    dbms_session.set_context( 'oow2009_CTX', 
                              'DOCTOR_ID', 
                              to_char(l_doctor_id) );   
  end login;             

  procedure logout
  as
  begin
    dbms_session.clear_context( 'oow2009_CTX' );
  end logout;     
end;
/
```

Create a policy function

```
create or replace function policy_view_own_patients( schema_p IN VARCHAR2,
                                                     table_p IN VARCHAR2 )  
  return VARCHAR2
is
begin
  return 'patient_id IN 
            (SELECT patient_id    
               FROM admission
              WHERE primary_doctor_id = 
                        SYS_CONTEXT( ''oow2009_CTX'', ''DOCTOR_ID'' ))';
end;
/
```

Create the row-level security policy

```
begin
  dbms_rls.add_policy (
    object_schema => 'oow2009',
    object_name   => 'PATIENT',
    policy_name   => 'VIEW_OWN_PATIENTS',
    policy_function => 'POLICY_VIEW_OWN_PATIENTS'
  );
end;
/
```

This query returns 0 rows now

```
select patient_first_name || ' ' || patient_last_name patient_name, 
       service_name, 
       doctor_last_name, 
       admission_date, 
       discharge_date
  from patient   p,
       doctor    d,
       service   s,
       admission a
 where p.patient_id = a.patient_id
   and a.service_id = s.service_id
   and a.primary_doctor_id = d.doctor_id
 order by patient_last_name;
```

If you log in as William Mayo, however

```
exec pkg_secure_context.login( 'William', 'Mayo' );
```

the same query now returns rows but only those that rows for Mayo's patients.  The other rows continue to be filtered out

```
select patient_first_name || ' ' || patient_last_name patient_name, 
       service_name, 
       doctor_last_name, 
       admission_date, 
       discharge_date
  from patient   p,
       doctor    d,
       service   s,
       admission a
 where p.patient_id = a.patient_id
   and a.service_id = s.service_id
   and a.primary_doctor_id = d.doctor_id
 order by patient_last_name;
```

Your policy function could drive off the currently logged in user or any other piece of information if you didn't want or need the secure context.

Comment: +1 BTW Oracle Row-Level-Security requires an Enterprise Edition license.